# Python, asyncore, asynchat, error on Python 2.7.3 Mac ONLY Bad file descriptor

Tags: python

I got a crash error when I try to force to disconnect user from my custom Python server.
I'm using asyncore and asynchat class.

But when I want to force the disconnection like this

```
asynchat.async_chat.close (self)
```

I got this error :

```
asyncore.loop()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 216, in loop
    poll_fun(timeout, map)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 145, in poll
    r, w, e = select.select(r, w, e, timeout)
select.error: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')
```

But only on Python Mac. No problem on Windows...

There is an execption in the code source of the asyncore.py class. But the server is crashing.

```
  try:
        r, w, e = select.select(r, w, e, timeout)
    except select.error, err:
        if err.args[0] != EINTR:
            raise
        else:
            return
```

So strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a thread on Google: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/589612-asyncore-select-statement-problem

This issue happens on OS X only.

Modify `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py` and set the default of `use_poll` from `False` to `True`:

Line 207:

```
def loop(timeout=30.0, use_poll=False, map=None, count=None):
```

to

```
def loop(timeout=30.0, use_poll=True, map=None, count=None):
```

Comment: It is not a very good idea to modify the `lib` files, better to control this on call, like so `asyncore.loop(use_poll=True)`